# unix tools to merge pdf

Tags: unix, pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

I'm looking for an alternate to ghostscript to merge pdf tools.

We generally have print jobs containing more than 3000 documents, which are to be merged into a pdf. Ghostscript does this whole operation in batches i.e. it creates intermediate small pdfs and then finally merges them all into the final single pdf. (which is good!!)

However the problem is that, after creating the intermediate pdfs, ghostscript takes a lot of time to create the final single pdf . Approximately 30 odd mins to merge 7 pdf files (each around 700 kb) into a 5.5 mb file.

So, i'm thinking to try an alternate to ghostscript for the last part i.e. to merge the intermediate pdfs into the final single pdf which would give me a faster output.

I tried searching online for **an alternative tool on unix for ghostscript**, but cant find one.

Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for open-source, free, commercial...?

Answer (score 3):

Try PDF toolkit...
http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output newFile.pdf

Comment: I thought pdf toolkit was only for windows , isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/), based on LaTeX.